Airflow DAG to copy csv fles (one or many) from GCS bucket to SFTP server
Below is the code. But i see certain issues with it.

not sure how to do it for more than one .csv files in the bucket
even though it copies to SFTP server, but it creates a staging directory in the destination path and then copies the file - like this recieving_dir\staging\*.csv

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_sftp import GCSToSFTPOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_gcs import GCSToGCSOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


gcs_bucket = 'adhoc_files'
staging_folder = 'staging'
archival_folder = 'archive'
SFTP_CONN_ID = "sftp_conn_id"

# Define your default arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    # 'retries': 1,
    # 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 4, 24),
}

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(
    'copy_from_gcs_to_sftp',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
)

# Define tasks
start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)

# Task to copy CSV file from GCS to SFTP
copy_to_sftp = GCSToSFTPOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_sftp',
    source_bucket=f"{gcs_bucket}",
    source_object=f"{staging_folder}/*.csv",  # Will pick up any CSV file in the bucket
    destination_path='recieving_dir/',
    sftp_conn_id=SFTP_CONN_ID,
    dag=dag,
)

# Task to move the file to the archival folder in the same GCS bucket
move_to_archive = BashOperator(
        task_id='archive_files',
        bash_command=f'gsutil mv gs://{source_gcs_bucket}/{staging_folder}/*.csv gs://{source_gcs_bucket}/{archival_folder}/'
    )
# Define task dependencies
start_task >> copy_to_sftp >> move_to_archive

